# Ruby / Rails: only pass parameter if condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have a line of HAML like this:

```
%li{:id=>node.shortcode, :class=>liclass unless liclass.empty? }
```

which doesn't work. I only want to pass the 'class' parameter if the condition provided isn't true. Is there a nice way to do this in Ruby will I just have to use an if/else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
%li{({:id=>node.shortcode}.merge(liclass.empty? ? {} : {:class=>liclass}) )}
```

It's not pretty, but it gives you the markup you're after.

Answer (score 1):

```
%li{:id=>node.shortcode, :class=>(liclass unless liclass.empty?)}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't assign class when `liclass` will be empty, but I'm not sure.
Try this:
`%li{:id=>node.shortcode, :class=>liclass }`

Comment: It does assign a class.  It looks like `class=''`.

Comment: Yeah, i did confuse it with `defined?`.